# Why does django give an httpresponse error when running my code?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am really struggling to figure out what is causing this error message:

> The view econlabs.views.balance didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

I feel like there is an issue with the form initialization in the balance function in views.py.

I don't know Django very well or Python. Please help me with this error. Code below:

*models.py*

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    userBalance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
```

*forms.py*

```
class BalanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Balance
        fields = ['userBalance']
```

*views.py*

```
def balance(request):
    form = BalanceForm(initial={"userBalance":107})
    if form.is_valid():
        if request.method == "POST" and "form10" in request.POST:
            formValue = form.cleaned_data.get('userBalance')
            form2 = formValue - 10
            return render(request, "econlabs/balance.html", {'form2': form2})
    return render(request, "econlabs/balance.html", {'form': form})
```

Comment: Can you check your indentation in `views.py` file, especially the last return? It doesn't seem right and I'm not sure if you've just pasted your code wrongly or is this indentation actually messed up in your file (as it may be actually relevant to your problem). You can edit the question to fix it, just remember to look at the preview before submitting the edit to make sure it is corrected.

Comment: the indention for view.py is correct in my actual code. I made the change on stack as well as you suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It returns none because the the code does not pass the line "if request.method == "POST" and "form10" in request.POST:"

Change your code to:

```
def balance(request):

    #POST
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Retrieving the form data as there is a POST request
        form = BalanceForm(request.POST)

        #Form validation
        if form.is_valid():
            #Retrieving userBalance input
            formValue = form.cleaned_data.get('userBalance')
            
            # Your calculation
            form2 = float(formValue) - 10.00

            #NOTE THAT form2 is a value and not a form set annymore 
            return render(request, "econlabs/balance.html", {'form2': form2})
    #GET
    else:
            form = BalanceForm()
            return render(request, "econlabs/balance.html", {'form': form})
```

Change:

```
userBalance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
```

To:

```
userBalance = models.FloatField(blank=True)
```

Comment: Hi Ayoub, I’m not even sure if I need to be using the post method and or modelForm Since the form data will actually come from the backend and is initialized to 107. The user will be clicking a button on the website and the form data will increment or decrement accordingly in the backend. That is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: You could better use AJAX.post in the front end in combination with JavaScript for that. To edit data in the backend with django-python you have to make a POST request.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=AJAX.post+django&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7xNj_5N3vAhWdgf0HHeu4DhAQ_AUoA3oECAEQBQ&biw=1920&bih=880

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ayoub. I implemented it but I continue to get the same error: the view econlabs.views.balance didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: Change your models, i have added the code for you